# explain the two conversions used in between hive date functions?

Tags: hive

i am trying to count the number of records in the particular date. 
eventually, got the query worked but confused between these two queries which seemed to same for me. why should i enclose the date_time instead of quote in the conversion.

when i hit the query,

```
select count(*) from TABLENAME 
where FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time), 'yyyyMMdd')='20170312';
```

result is count of the particular date is arrived.

but when i hit,

```
select count(*) from TABLENAME 
where FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('date_time', 'yyyyMMdd'))='20170312';
```

the result is 0.

please explain the difference of these queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_time` is a column while `'date_time'` is a string and the attempt to use it as date result in NULL.
If you want to qualify the column name you should use `date_time`

Comment: how about using without quotes like FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time, 'yyyyMMdd'))='20170312';

Comment: ideally, first example works. can you please say why is it third example does not work as i dont use string to represent.

Comment: I just notice that the example in your comment is different from the 1st example in the post. The closing bracket (`)`) is not in the same place.